# what does Format specifier int* & double* warning message mean?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, header, math.h

**My program is to get `(a^b)%c`** .
my program -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double powfunction (double x, double y)
{
    double answer = pow(x,y);
    return answer;
}
int main()
{
    int t, result, c, asign;
    double a, b;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(t;t>0;t--){
        scanf("%lf %lf %d",&a,&b,&c);
        asign=powfunction(a,b);
        printf("%d",asign%c);
    }
}
```

**I named it `tt.c` . when I tried to run the program writing `gcc -o tt tt.c -lm`  in linux terminal it's giving the following output.**

```
tt.c:9:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
    9 | main()
      | ^~~~
tt.c: In function ‘main’:
tt.c:15:12: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
   15 |   scanf("%lf %lf %d",a,b,c);
      |          ~~^         ~
      |            |         |
      |            double *  double
tt.c:15:16: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 3 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
   15 |   scanf("%lf %lf %d",a,b,c);
      |              ~~^       ~
      |                |       |
      |                |       double
      |                double *
tt.c:15:19: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   15 |   scanf("%lf %lf %d",a,b,c);
      |                  ~^      ~
      |                   |      |
      |                   int *  int
pronay@MackbookPro:~$
```

**After printing this the program is exited.
Any solution for this?**

**I used `gcc -o tt tt.c -lm`  cmd to run it because someone said this is how to link the math library**

Comment: Pass the variable **addresses** (**&**) to *scanf*. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: didnot get it ...

Comment: You've omitted the`&` before each variable in `scanf("%lf %lf %d",a,b,c);`. As you have included this in the earlier call to `scanf`, I can only assume it's a typo.

Comment: `scanf("%lf %lf %d",a,b,c);` --> `scanf("%lf %lf %d",&a,&b,&c)`;

Comment: I fixed it, but still same msg

Answer (score 0):

> The additional arguments should point to already allocated objects of
> the type specified by their corresponding format specifier within the
> format string.

You are passing the variables by value to `scanf`. However `scanf` expects pointers to the variables. You need to do this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double powfunction (double x, double y)
{
    double answer = pow(x,y);
    return answer;
}
main()
{
    int t, result, c, asign;
    double a, b;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(t;t>0;t--){
        //pass pointers to a, b, c instead
        scanf("%lf %lf %d",&a,&b,&c);
        asign=powfunction(a,b);
        printf("%d",asign%c);
    }
}
```

Also the main function should have this signature

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

or

```
int main(void)
```

and should return an integer value. If it does not, the return value is assumed to be 0.

Comment: ```#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double powfunction (double x, double y)
{
 double answer = pow(x,y);
 int answer1=answer;
 return answer1;
}
int main()
{
 int t, result, c, asign;
 double a, b;
 scanf("%d",&t);
 for(t;t>0;t--){
  scanf("%lf %lf %d",&a,&b,&c);
  asign=powfunction(a,b);
  printf("%d",asign%c);
 }
}```

Comment: I made my program like this

Comment: its now

showing `/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file source: Is a directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
 now

Comment: @PronaySarker That means the name you're giving to the resulting executable is the name of an existing directory.  Use a different name, or rename / remove the directory.

Comment: I did it right before 2/3 mins, but it's not taking any input. Just exiting the programm

Comment: The `main` function can also have the prototype: `int main(void)`

Comment: And according to C99, if `main` doesn't explicitly return a value, it is assumed it returns 0.

Comment: Right, edited the answer. Imo not returning a value is something you should do, but i guess its an option after all.